# Unit couchdb.service failed to load: No such file or directory

Tags: gentoo, systemd, sabayon

I have couchdb on Sabayon running

```
# couchdb -version
getopt: invalid option -- 'v'

Try `couchdb -h' for more information.
kernel-poll not supported; "K" parameter ignored
Apache CouchDB 1.5.0 (LogLevel=info) is starting.
Apache CouchDB has started. Time to relax.
[info] [<0.32.0>] Apache CouchDB has started on http://127.0.0.1:5984/
```

However, I can not use systemctl:

```
# systemctl enable couchdb
Failed to issue method call: No such file or directory

# systemctl start couchdb
Failed to issue method call: Unit couchdb.service failed to load: No such file or directory.
```

How is it possible to fix?

Comment: you should learn to use systemd. tl;dr: `systemctl | grep couchdb`

Comment: Unfortunately, systemctl | grep couchdb finds nothing.

Comment: look at the list of files that the package installs for `.service` files in `/usr/share/systemd/system` (IIRC).

Comment: # ls /usr/share/systemd/ shows me only kbd-model-map

Comment: According to my output for emerge -av couchdb there is NO systemd USE flag, which means you'd need to write a Service File.  Try ls -al /etc/init.d | grep couch.  If no results are returned this package cannot be autostarted using init systems

Comment: ls -al /etc/init.d | grep couch finds couchdb